# wix path changes not appearing in an exec command

Tags: excel, wix, windows-installer, vba

I am installing a DLL into my programs own directory, I am adding myself to the path environment variable.

```
<Environment Id="NewEnvironment1" Name="Path" Value="[INSTALLDIR]Core" Separator=";" Action="set" Part="last" Permanent="no" System="yes" />
```

I then call a visual basic program that then uses excel that needs to use the DLL on the path. It is Excel that is complaining it can not find my DLL.

```
<CustomAction Id='LaunchXLAReg' FileKey='RegisterXLAs' ExeCommand="" Execute='commit' Return='asyncNoWait' />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
            <Custom Action="LaunchXLAReg" Before="InstallFinalize">NOT Installed</Custom>
            <Custom Action="LaunchXLAUnReg" Before="InstallFinalize">Installed AND NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

but when i printed out the path environment variable from within the visual basic my changes were not present, so the VB failed.

I then tried using the visual basic to set the path env variable, but this time the variable wasn't set on my system at the end of the installation process.

This is on windows 8.1 it used to work on windows 7
Edit: added the InstallExecuteSequence block, added clarification of which program is producing the error.

Comment: I have cross-posted this to the wix usergroup

Comment: I would try running it within the execution context. (before InstallFinalize; execute="deferred"). My hunch here is that you are running the ExeCommand from the UI's context. I'm guessing the UI's context has a copy of the environment vars from when the msi was launched and that the path variable you added was not picked up due to the 'cached' values. If you run within the ExecuteSequence's context, it should see the environment variable you set. Sort of like if you open two cmd prompts and set an env var in one then try to access it in another it won't be there until you open a new one.

Comment: @BrianSutherland do you mean like the InstallExecute block I just added?

Comment: Yes something like that. You'll have to update your Execute in the CustomAction definition to be "deferred" and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Installer doesn't flush the environment variables to the system until the end of the install. It's not wise to commit them to the system until the install has actually succeeded and can't roll back - I think that's part of the reason. Also you are running as the child process of a service that doesn't pick up environment variables until a reboot.

It might work if your program can do the SystemParametersInfo call with the SPIF_SENDCHANGE setting:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947(v=vs.85).aspx

that will broadcast this, but your program would need to handle the change message here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725497(v=vs.85).aspx

However, if you are running the exe from your own installed program directory and is deferred and after files have been installed, then it's not clear why it's not working because the Dll is right next to the exe, correct? So that means that if you specify a Directory in your custom action (which should be a type 34 or 35) then this will be the working directory. The WiX docs don't seem clear (to me) on this point but the custom action documentation clearly says that you can specify a directory as the working directory for your executable:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372048(v=vs.85).aspx

See types 34 and 35. See also the WiX documentation that talks about using the Directory attribute:

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/customaction.html

In other words I think it all might just work if you use a directory of [INSTALLDIR] in your custom action specification.

Comment: As I have changed my original post to say, it is Excel that is missing the DLLs not my VB program.  My VB program calls excel to register other VBA scripts.